# Identities for powers of functions based on generalization of Lagrange interpolation

Tags: polynomials, sequences-and-series, integer-sequences, interpolation, exponential-polynomials

[Lagrange polynomial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange_polynomial) can be used to obtain an identity:
$$(k+t)^n = \sum_{i=0}^n (k+d_i)^n \prod_{\substack{j=0\\ j\not=i}}^n \frac{t-d_j}{d_i-d_j},$$
which holds for any integer $n>0$, any real numbers $k,t$, and any *distinct* real numbers $d_0,\dots,d_n$. The key idea is that the difference between the left-hand and right-hand sides represents a polynomial of degree $\leq n$ in $t$, while it has $n+1$ zeros $d_0,\dots,d_n$. The [fundamental theorem of algebra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_theorem_of_algebra) then implies that this polynomial is zero.

The same identity can restated in terms of function $f(t)=t$ as
$$(\star)\qquad f(k+t)^n = \sum_{i=0}^n f(k+d_i)^n \prod_{\substack{j=0\\ j\not=i}}^n \frac{f(t-d_j)}{f(d_i-d_j)}.$$

---

Recently I [learned](http://dxdy.ru/topic120476.html) that the identity $(\star)$ holds for (non-polynomial) function $f(t)=U_t=U_t(P,Q)$ being [Lucas sequence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lucas_sequence) (equivalently, $U_t=\frac{a^t-b^t}{a-b}$, where $a,b$ are the zeros of the characteristic polynomial, which enables real values for $t$). That is,
$$U_{k+t}^n=\sum_{i=0}^{n} U_{k+d_i}^n\prod_{\substack{j=0\\ j\not=i}}^{n}\frac{U_{t-d_j}}{U_{d_i-d_j}},$$
where again $n>0$ is integer, $k,t$ are any real numbers, and $d_0,\dots,d_n$ are any  *distinct* real numbers.

<s>What would be the analog of the fundamental theorem of algebra here?</s>
As pointed out by Fedor Petrov, the difference here represents a polynomial of degree $\leq n$ in $(a/b)^t$, and the same arguments hold.

---

What would be other interesting examples of $f(t)$, for which the identity $(\star)$ holds?

Comment: Both parts are $b^{nt}$ times a polynomial in $(a/b)^t$ of degree at most $n$, right?

Comment: @FedorPetrov: Indeed. So this still appeals to the fundamental theorem of algebra. I guess this can be generalized to other functions, such as $\sin(t)$ (based on Euler's formula).

Comment: I think, $\sin x=(e^{ix}-e^{-ix})/2i$ is essentially the same example

Comment: @Somos: What particular identities you refer to in your code?

Comment: @Max Alekseyev: The id4_3_1_2a, id5_4_1_5c, id6_5_1_9. The last I added earlier today.

Comment: It also works for elliptic functions $f(t)=\text{sn}(t,k)$.

Comment: More generally, $f(t)=a\sin(bt)$ where $a,b$ are constants. See my [Special Algebraic Identities](https://grail.eecs.csuohio/~somos/ident04.gp).